# Generate DDL Script to create database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating an application using Entity Framework code-first.

How can I create the database using this model? Is it possible to create the DDL scripts from a code-first approach just like the DDL scripts that can be generated from a model first approach?

Update : Generate a sql server script from Entity Framework code-first architecture

Comment: Isn't the entire point of code-first that you don't *need* to generate DDL scripts?

Comment: DLL script to create my database depend on my classes

Comment: @Daniel Infrastructure guy gave me a pre-existing database without tables and strict permissions to run "create tables script". That is fair common to justify, even if the entire point of code-first that you don't need to generate DDL scripts

Comment: or what if you screw it up and need to check what it is supposed to be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Entity Framework Code-First the application, when run, will create the database and tables that support your .Net model classes.  Therefore using this approach you don't need DDL scripts as the work will be done for you by the application.

In Entity Framework there has been a lot of effort put into the Migrations tool to enable the deployment of db changes.  This is detailed here:

- [Automatic Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735)
- [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621)

This seems to offer the most effective way of deploying db changes to multiple target environments.

Code First is not particularly capable when it comes to local database deltas.  If you are doing anything with OnModelCreating within your db context then this will require your database to be deleted then recreated by the code first application.  This is required by code first to ensure that the code model and the persistence model are kept synchronised.

These are two good starter tutorials on MVC with an EF component.

[Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

[Intro to ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs)

Comment: ok,thanks i just following to find this :
"Using Entity Framework Code-First the application when will create the database and tables"
thanks dude

Comment: Not always - I've tried the sqlite db with entities and all you get is a DDL script - the tables are not created for you.